# Setting a class variable with a private method

Tags: c++, oop

Say, we have a class that has internal state, implemented as a private variable and a method to determine that state. What is the oop-way to set the variable with a method:

```
class Car
{
..
private:
float speed_;
float calculate_optimal_speed();
..}
```

Is it better to make a function calculate_optimal_speed(), which returns the varible speed_ within its body or a void set_speed() method?

Say, we have a big method control_the_car().
What is preferred and will create less problem in the further development of the code:

```
float calculate_optimal_speed();
control_the_car()
{
..
speed_ = calculate_optimal_speed();
}
```

or

```
void set_optimal_speed();
control_the_car();
{
..
set_optimal_speed();
}
```

On one hand, implementing set_optimal_speed() allows to change the type of speed_ variable with less modifications of the code. On the other hand, returning a value allows to re-use the function if I need it again. Is there a rule of thumb here?

Comment: As its the classes own interna, direct access is fine.

Comment: It is use-case specific, but in general you make the member variable private, then make public setters (modifiers) and getters (accessors).

Comment: Beware though: Just making member variables private and providing getter+setter does not really provide encapsulation.

Comment: I would use "calculate" instead of "set", because of MVC principle.

Comment: @Arkady, how would MVC (I assume you mean model-view-controller) impose the calculate implementation?

Comment: Why not do both - set_optimal_speed(calculate_optimal_speed()) first one responsibility is to exclusively set the value and do some sanity cheks if these are needed and the second one responsibility is calculating the optimal speed. If for some reason calculating gives result that is unacceptable by set, then it can adjust the result. But in such case I would go just with plain field access. So it depends.

Comment: @utnapistim, I mean I would try to split entity "speed" and operation "calculate_optimal_speed" to different entities. Second one is finished logical brick. "speed" - is data in some state. So, I would split it to two separated bricks instead of creating one: giving hidden access to data of entity "speed" from control.

Comment: @Arkady, thanks for explaining. I guess that would be the next step (but it depends on whatever needs OP has for the code).

Comment: @utnapistim, yes, on this step, choosing between those tho variants, that is reason why I would choose "calculate", and nothing more. Just more flexible variant, and less covered dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a rule of thumb here?

Yes: write the simplest implementation that covers your needs. If you need something different later, refactor.

This means you should probably use the `set_optimal_speed();` implementation, unless you have speeds to calculate that do not need to be set in the private state of the class (if you do, make a function that returns the speed, then implement `set_optimal_speed();` in terms of this function).

Answer (score 0):

Having getters and setters can help you maintain and organize your code

```
class Car {
private:
   // A private variable named speed_ of type float
   float speed_;
   float calculate_optimal_speed();
public:
   // Constructor
   Car(float x) { speed_ = x; }
   // OR
   Car(float speed_) { this->speed_ = speed_; }

   // A getter for variable speed_ of type T receives no argument and return a value of type float
   float getspeed_() const { return speed_; }

   // A setter for variable speed_ of type float receives a parameter of type float and return void
   void setspeed_(float x) { speed_ = x; }
   // OR
   void setspeed_(float speed_) { this->speed_ = speed_; }
}

control_the_car()
{
..
 x = calculate_optimal_speed()
 void setspeed_(float x) { speed_ = x; } ;
}
```

This way if you need to update speed variable you can use Setter to update it

Comment: Nice exhibition of an anti-pattern: The non-encapsulating encapsulation (similar to the non-abstracting abstraction).

Comment: @SaiRamSudheer, the getter and setter you added are an antipattern, because they simply expose an implementation detail. You should generally be wary of trivial getters and setters: they indicate the x-y problem: you need to do something with a car's speed in client code, and instead of going `carinstance.do_stuff_with_speed()` you go `auto speed = carinstance.getspeed_(); /* do something with speed here */`. This is equivalent to declaring `Car::speed_` as public = `Car` is a bad class: it shows it's _privates_ to client code.